# Starting Hadoop single node cluster in virtual machine

Tags: hadoop, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm trying to start a Hadoop single node cluster in my Ubuntu virtual machine (virtualbox).
I had no trouble doing it in my Windows host, but in my VM the following message appears:

[image]

I think this is because I have `localhost` written somewhere, but because I am in a virtual machine I have to write a different IP.

Can someone help me?
Thank you so much.

Comment: `echo $JAVA_HOME`... It will be empty... The error doesn't lie. You need to install Java and setup the PATH variables

Comment: It is not empty, that's the problem. I did exactly that, and it returned the path to my Java directory.

Comment: But because I have `localhost`, I'm guessing it is not searching for the JAVA_HOME in the right place.

Comment: Your IP address/hostname doesn't affect PATH variables. The user account you start the services as does, though.

Comment: If you really feel like changing it though, feel free to edit `/etc/hosts`

Comment: Thank you, I will try. This is what prints when I do `echo $JAVA_HOME`: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386`

Comment: You could open the `start-dfs.sh` file in a text editor to see where it crashes to generate that message. At least, that's what I would do because that error doesn't make sense if the variable is, in fact, set.

Comment: You can try by entering manually `JAVA_HOME` in `hadoop-env.sh`